# cannot create database using mySQLi

Tags: php, database, insert, mysqli, set

I'm always getting error when inserting the value to my database. but it's working when i'm using mySQL only, I'm new to SQLi so please be gentel.

insert.php

```
    <?php
    include("dbinfo.inc.php");

    //connect to mysql server
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

    //check if any connection error was encountered
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
        exit;
    }     

    //insert    
    $query = "insert into client_info set (
    id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string('')."',
    first = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['first'])."',
    last = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['last'])."',
    phone = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone'])."',
    mob = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['mob'])."',
    fax = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fax'])."',
    email = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',
    web = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['web'])."',
    com = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['com'])."',
    address = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['address'])."',
    city = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['city'])."',
    state = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['state'])."',
    zip = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['zip'])."',
    zone = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['zone'])."',
    office = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['office'])."',
    office_num = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['office_num'])."',
    ext_mob = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ext_mob'])."',
    ext_phone = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ext_phone'])."',
    ext_office = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ext_office'])."',
    srv = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['srv'])."',
    stype = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['stype'])."',
    voip = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['voip'])."',
    vpass = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['vpass'])."',
    regDate = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['regDate'])."',
    acct = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['acct'])."',
    Nagents = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Nagents'])."',
    agents = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['agents'])."',
    password = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'
    )";

        //execute the query
        if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
            //if saving success
            echo "User was created.";
        }else{
            //if unable to create new record
            echo "Database Error: Unable to create record.";
        }
        //close database connection
        $mysqli->close();


    ?>
```

create.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="JavaScript">
var today=new Date();
var jran=today.getTime();

function random() {
    ia=9301;
    ic=49297;
    im=233280;
    jran = (jran*ia+ic) % im;
    return jran/(im*1.0);
};

function rand(number) {
    return Math.ceil(random()*number);
};

function makearray(n) {
    this.length = n;
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) this[i] = 0;
    return this;
}

var asciitable = new makearray (128);
asciitable.length=128;
for (var i=0;i<=127;i++) asciitable[i]="";
asciitable[33]="!"; asciitable[34]="\""; 
asciitable[35]="#"; asciitable[36]="$";
asciitable[37]="%"; asciitable[38]="&"; 
asciitable[39]="'"; asciitable[40]="(";
asciitable[41]=")"; asciitable[42]="*"; 
asciitable[43]="+"; asciitable[44]=",";
asciitable[45]="-"; asciitable[46]="."; 
asciitable[47]="/"; asciitable[48]="0";
asciitable[49]="1"; asciitable[50]="2"; 
asciitable[51]="3"; asciitable[52]="4";
asciitable[53]="5"; asciitable[54]="6"; 
asciitable[55]="7"; asciitable[56]="8";
asciitable[57]="9"; asciitable[58]=":"; 
asciitable[59]=";"; asciitable[60]="<";
asciitable[61]="="; asciitable[62]=">"; 
asciitable[63]="?"; asciitable[64]="@";
asciitable[65]="A"; asciitable[66]="B"; 
asciitable[67]="C"; asciitable[68]="D";
asciitable[69]="E"; asciitable[70]="F"; 
asciitable[71]="G"; asciitable[72]="H";
asciitable[73]="I"; asciitable[74]="J"; 
asciitable[75]="K"; asciitable[76]="L";
asciitable[77]="M"; asciitable[78]="N"; 
asciitable[79]="O"; asciitable[80]="P";
asciitable[81]="Q"; asciitable[82]="R"; 
asciitable[83]="S"; asciitable[84]="T";
asciitable[85]="U"; asciitable[86]="V"; 
asciitable[87]="W"; asciitable[88]="X";
asciitable[89]="Y"; asciitable[90]="Z"; 
asciitable[91]="["; asciitable[92]="\\";
asciitable[93]="]"; asciitable[94]="^"; 
asciitable[95]="_"; asciitable[96]="`";
asciitable[97]="a"; asciitable[98]="b"; 
asciitable[99]="c"; asciitable[100]="d";
asciitable[101]="e"; asciitable[102]="f"; 
asciitable[103]="g"; asciitable[104]="h";
asciitable[105]="i"; asciitable[106]="j"; 
asciitable[107]="k"; asciitable[108]="l";
asciitable[109]="m"; asciitable[110]="n"; 
asciitable[111]="o"; asciitable[112]="p";
asciitable[113]="q"; asciitable[114]="r"; 
asciitable[115]="s"; asciitable[116]="t";
asciitable[117]="u"; asciitable[118]="v"; 
asciitable[119]="w"; asciitable[120]="x";
asciitable[121]="y"; asciitable[122]="z"; 
asciitable[123]="{"; asciitable[124]="|";
asciitable[125]="}"; asciitable[126]="~";

function nchar(num) {
    if ((num>=33) && (num<=127)) return asciitable[num];
}

function doit() {
    var i;
    var n;
    var s = "";
            for (i=1;i<=8;i++) {
                n=0;
                while ( (n<=47) || 
                                        ((n>=58) && (n<=96)) || 
                                        (n>=123))  n = rand(126);
                s = s + nchar(n);
            }

    document.gen.password.value = s;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="insert.php" name="gen">
<b>Personal Info:</b>
<p>First Name:<input type="text" name="first" size="20" /></p>
<p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="last" size="20" /></p>
<p>Mob:<input type="text" name="mob" size="20" />
ext:<input type="text" name="ext_mob" size="4" /></p>
<p>Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" size="20" />
ext:<input type="text" name="ext_phone" size="4" /></p>
<p>Fax:<input type="text" name="fax" size="20" /></p>
<p>E-mail:<input type="text" name="email" size="35" />
<p>Address:<input type="text" name="address" size="40" /></p>
<p>City:<input type="text" name="city" size="20" /></p>
<p>State:<input type="text" name="state" size="20" /></p>
<p>Zip Code:<input type="text" name="zip" size="5" /></p>
<p>Zone:<input type="text" name="zone" size="5" /></p>
<br>

<b>Office Info:</b>
<p>Company:<input type="text" name="com" size="40" /></p>
<p>Office Address:<input type="text" name="office" size="40" /></p>
<p>Office Num #:<input type="text" name="office_num" size="15" />
ext:<input type="text" name="ext_office" size="4" /></p>
<p>Website:<input type="text" name="web" size="30" /></p><br>
<b>Account Info:</b>
<p>Registry Date:<input type="text" name="regDate" size="30" /></p>
<p>Account:<input type="text" name="acct" size="20" /></p>
<p>Service:<input type="text" name="srv" size="15" /></p>
<p>Service Type:<input type="text" name="stype" size="40" /></p>
<p>Number of Agents:<input type="text" name="Nagents" size="3" /></p><br>


<b>Agent Info:</b>
<p>Agents:<input type="text" name="agents" size="40" /></p>
<p>VOID:<input type="text" name="voip" size="20" /></p>
<p>VOIP Password:<input type="text" name="vpass" size="20" /></p>
<br>

<input type="hidden" size="20" name="password">

<input type="submit" name="go" value="Insert to Database" onclick="doit()">
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

the error i get is when the scripts tries to insert the query to the DB

"Database Error: Unable to create record."

i tried to see if there are any output on my form, and there is, even tried to insert just one variable "first" still getting errors, don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Use `$mysqli->error` to get the actual error message instead of echoing your error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `SET` syntax in `INSERT` statement, you should not use parenthesis around it.

```
-- One way to insert
INSERT INTO table SET col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2';

-- other way
INSERT INTO table(col1,col2) VALUES('val1','val2');
```

Also use native [errors provided by the driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see what's wrong with your query